# How does This Killing Fire work?

Tags: dungeon-world

The text of Immolator's advanced move **This Killing Fire** says:

> Add the following tags to your options for Burning Brand: *messy*, *forceful*, *reach*, *near*, *far*.

Given that there are the options:

- *hand*
- *thrown*, *near*
- +1 damage
- remove the *dangerous* tag

Does the **This Killing Fire** talent increase your options pool to nine options? Like so:

- *hand*
- *thrown*, *near*
- +1 damage
- remove the *dangerous* tag
- *messy*
- *forceful*
- *reach*
- *near*
- *far*

I'm confused because I don't exactly know what the difference between **thrown, near** and just **near** are, considering they are different tags on the equipment section. I can't think of any situations where it matters if the fire is being flung at the enemy in the form of a flaming arrow (near), or as a throwing dagger (near, thrown).

Comment: I guess they included the extra *near* by mistake as I see no difference either. If you think of the tags very creatively, *thrown* might be even better as it could allow you to lob your fire in a ballistic arc instead of shooting it (if you would not allow that without *thrown* anyway).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, your options expand.

The difference between **thrown, near** and **near** is that the latter is not thrown. That might not seem like much difference from a mechanical perspective, but in my experience with Dugeon World, there a many opportunities for unusual situations to arise where small *fictional* differences can make all the difference.

So when picking which to use, make it fit the style of your character, but otherwise don't worry about it. If it ever matters you'll know it when it happens, and then it will be good to be clear about what you're physically doing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do we have any Word of God on this one - that is *why* was bare **near** added? It just seems so strange and confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between *near* and *thrown, near* is that a *thrown* weapon is lost when it is thrown and must be recovered, and you cannot choose to mark off extra ammo (or in this case, an extra use) on a 7-9 but must deal less damage or put yourself in danger to get the shot.

The **burning brand** itself is a singular weapon of pure flame. Throwing it when it still had uses remaining would leave it burning wherever you threw it to, and you would have to recover it to continue making use of it. Letting it operate with just the *near* or *far* tags means it can hurl bolts of flame or copies of itself or whatever fictional convenience lets you attack at range and still keep hold of it.